# Azure Scheduler to remove old azure-sql-database-entries, possible?

Tags: sql, database, azure, scheduler

As the title is stating my question. i am wondering if this is possible and in that case what should i read on? Anyone done this before?

Ok so to be clear - what i want to do is:

- Clear old entires in a database, preiodically. That is for example
  clear all  entries in a database table that are 1 month old.
- Possible to use Azure Scheduler to automate this for azure sql
  Database?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi John - Need to know a little bit more about what you're trying to do, do you mind update your questions to be more precise?

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I hope that made the picture a bit clearer.

Comment: How are you doing this today? Is there an HTTP endpoint that you call, or maybe a stored procedure?

Comment: We managed to do the work with the help of the "job" being written in an API having the correct functionality. And using the scheduler to trigger the API as a Delete function wich in turn will do what we where looking for. 

I dont know if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your description, I see a two options for you using Azure services to do this with ease -

- Maintain your current API, and set up Azure Scheduler to call the API on a defined schedule. This is how most Scheduler users use the service for and will fit your need.
- Rewrite the clean up logic as a stored procedure, and use Azure Logic Apps to trigger the stored procedure on a defined schedule. The benefit for this is that there's no more code to maintain/host besides the stored procedure.

Comment: Both suggestions where great, It works Perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear @John, please feel free to reach out to me anytime for any questions and suggestions regarding both Logic Apps and Scheduler service at Derek.Li (at) microsoft dot com.